# Add multiple values to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am doing a riddle guessing game. This relies on the user getting the question correct (obviously) to progress, so the user's answer must match the question answer stored in a dictionary. This will make the quiz incredibly difficult if they don't get the exact wording the same, so is it possible to add multiple versions of a correct answer to cover this? I am using a json file, with simple "question" and "answer" keys. I have this so far, (which throws up all kinds of errors!) but hopefull yyou will get the gist of what I'm after:

```
[
{
    "question": "I'm so fast you can't see me, though everyone else can see straight through me. I don't stop until the day you die. What am I?",
    "answer": (("The blink of an eye"),("Blink of an eye"),("Blink of eye"),("Eye blink"))

}
```

]

Thanks!

Comment: If that code is from your json, you should use `[]` for the arrays ([see doc](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)) and no `()` around the strings. I mean this `"answer": ["The blink of an eye", "Blink of an eye",...]`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store the answers in a list?

```
{
    "question": "I'm so fast you can't see me, though everyone else can see straight through me. I don't stop until the day you die. What am I?",
    "answer": ["The blink of an eye","Blink of an eye","Blink of eye","Eye blink"]    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this:**
The use of array in this situation is good option. In your question the json format is wrong. Therefore you are facing the issue.

```
[{
    "question": "I'm so fast you can't see me, though everyone else can see straight through me. I don't stop until the day you die. What am I?",
    "answer": ["The blink of an eye", "Blink of an eye", "Eye blink"]

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to other choices instead of storing all the possible answers, try just store a single answer and compare the string similarity between user's response to the correct answer.

Some common similarity measures such as Leveinstain distance should work pretty well, also there's a nice library called [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) which deals with cases such as 'blink of eye' vs 'eye blink' (the ordering)

Comment: Ok perfect. I shall see if I can work this one out using this library. Thanks for the input.

Comment: np, glad it helps :)